# Unused variable in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm currently coding a LinkedList implementation in C. I'm stumbling on the following problem: `variable 'currentNode' set but not used.`

I don't really understand this. I'm using the currentNode variable!

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node root;
    root.val = 0;
    root.next = NULL;

    struct node currentNode;
    currentNode = root;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        struct node newNode;
        newNode.val = i;
        currentNode.next = &newNode;

        currentNode = newNode;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're trying to allocate linked list nodes on the stack. This won't work; Each `newNode` goes out of scope and is deallocated after each `for` loop iteration. You need to `malloc` the nodes instead, and refer to each node by reference.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Hopefully there would be a second warning, "`newNode` is set but never used", if the OP removed `currentNode` from the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are never *reading* the `currentNode` variable. If you removed all lines that mention the variable, your program would be exactly the same.

(This is indeed a useful warning: in your case, which presumably was intended to build up a list of ten elements, it points to a fatal bug in your code which means that the actual code does nothing.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should probably mention that this warning only happens if you use `-Wall` or specifically `-Wunused-but-set-variable`.

Second, `gcc`'s definition of `usage` is reading from a variable, not assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

i found another problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node * next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node root;
    root.val = 0;
    root.next = NULL;

    struct node currentNode;
    currentNode = root;

    // .... 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // newNode is a temporary value, 
        // its life time end before the next cycle 
        // u should new it 
        struct node newNode;
        newNode.val = i;
        currentNode.next = &newNode;

        currentNode = newNode;
    }

    // ...maybe like this 
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        struct node* pNewNode = (struct node*)malloc(siof(struct node));
        pNewNode->val = i;
        currentNode.next = pNewNode;

        currentNode = *pNewNode;
    }

    // free node
    // ... 

    return 0;
}
```